# zsh function throwing "Bad math expression: illegal character" error

Tags: zsh

I want to create a simple function which prints the size of a file with the appropriate label that is accessed via curl. This is what I have included in my `.zshrc` config:

```
function curl-size {
  BYTELENGTH=$(curl -sI $1 | grep -i Content-Length | awk '{print $2}')
  if (($BYTELENGTH>1000000000));then
    VALUE=$(echo "scale=3;$BYTELENGTH/1000000000" | bc -l)
    LABEL="gb"
  elif (($BYTELENGTH>1000000));then
    VALUE=$(echo "scale=3;$BYTELENGTH/1000000" | bc -l)
    LABEL="mb"
  elif (($BYTELENGTH>1000));then
    VALUE=$(echo "scale=3;$BYTELENGTH/1000" | bc -l)
    LABEL="kb"
  else
    VALUE=$BYTELENGTH
    LABEL="bytes"
  fi
  echo $(echo "$VALUE" | grep -o '.*[1-9]') $LABEL
}
```

trying to use `curl-size https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg` in the terminal returns

```
curl-size:2: bad math expression: illegal character: ^M
curl-size:5: bad math expression: illegal character: ^M
curl-size:8: bad math expression: illegal character: ^M
curl-size:12: bad math expression: illegal character: ^M
```

Comment: (1) bash, or zsh? They're two very different, mutually-incompatible shells; you should be tagging for one or the other, but not both. (2) This specific issue is caused by the very first thing in the "Before Asking About Problematic Code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info -- though it's possible the carriage returns are in the content returned by `curl` rather than in your input files, the same fixes apply.

Comment: BTW, if your shell is bash (or actually any other POSIX-compliant shell) as opposed to zsh (which intentionally breaks from the standard's mandated unquoted string-splitting behaviors), there are some quoting bugs here -- run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ to have them identified for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy valid point

Comment: If it's zsh, btw, you don't actually need `bc` here -- the shell has native floating-point math.

Comment: Looks like the data returned by curl has DOS line termination with `\r\n`. You can either use dos2unix, or place a `sed 's/^M//g'` in the pipeline (where ^M is a literal \r, entered with CTRL-V CTRL-M).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point, I have clarified my comment.

Comment: Ahh. I'd consider writing that as `sed $'s/\r//g'`, to have copy/paste-able code (at the expense of portability to shells that don't honor [ANSI C-like strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, that's not POSIXly enough :-) But yes, zsh understands `$'foo'` syntax. Anyway, your tr solution is better. +1

Comment: Thanks all so much. Not terribly experienced with shell script stuff and was using this little function as a way to learn a bit more about how this stuff works, so all of the comments have been helpful :)

Comment: @Brice, ...btw, you might want to get in the habit of using `<<<"$foo"` instead of `echo "$foo" |`; it's often a bit faster to execute, and among the shells that support it, has more consistent behavior; if portability is more important than performance, by contrast, `printf '%s\n' "$foo" |` is a clear win over `echo` -- see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^M` is the character otherwise known as a carriage return -- which is to say, an instruction for the cursor to go back to the beginning of the current line. On DOS-derived platforms, lines of a text file are *separated* by a `<CR><LF>` sequence (whereas on UNIX-family platforms, lines of a text file are *terminated* by `<LF>` alone; note that this means that on UNIX, a text file is expected to have a `<LF>` at the very end for that last line to be valid, whereas on Windows, a trailing `<CR><LF>` results in an empty line at the end of the file).

---

If the web server you're connecting to with `curl` is returning content with DOS newlines, those carriage returns will be considered content rather than code. A somewhat inefficient but workable fix might look like:

```
BYTELENGTH=$(curl -sI "$1" | tr -d '\r' | awk '/Content-Length/ {print $2}')
```

<sub>Note that using all-caps names for your own variables is a bad idea when writing scripts for POSIX-compliant shells -- which by [standard-mandated convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) reserve lowercase names for application use and use exclusively the all-caps namespace for variables that modify their behavior -- but zsh is *not* POSIX-compliant and does not follow this convention, so this guideline does not apply there.</sub>